# Tableau Data Connection filter (User Managed)

Tags: visualization, data-visualization, tableau-api

I have Big table in vertica which has time_stamp. I want to create global data connection filter for all worksheet, because all worksheets going to query data from same table. So this Data connection filter give option to specify start date and end date in this filter to query the data. So far I am able to create this Dataconnection filter but not able to make it flexible to change, also this filter would be placed on dashboard along with other worksheets.

Any help on this  please ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know much about Vertica, but why exactly do you want to do this filter? If it's for performance reasons (querying little data is faster than querying much data), ok. All I can say it's I don't know how to make a data connection filter flexible.

But it if it is for visualization purpose (show data only for a specific time frame), then you shouldn't worry about filtering the connection, and focus on filtering the display. Basically you can create 2 parameters (start date and end date) and create a calculated field to see if the time_stamp is between those parameters, and filter by it.

Answer (score 1):

First we need to create two parameter(min_date,max_date).first parameter1 and give any name and select datatype:date and current date:give what ever you want.and select range,range value min and suppose 
min:12/3/2013 and set from field:your datasource and select orderdate.
create calculated field1:
[parametername]-1>=[orderdate].
second parameter2:same above but range max:27/7/2014(what ever).
create calculated field2:
[parametername]+1<=[orderdate].